# How concat very long clob in pl sql without error

Tags: oracle, plsql, concatenation, clob

Hi I'm making a new plsql function with this declaration:

```
string_result CLOB;
string1 CLOB;
string2 CLOB;
```

In my body I have:

```
...
for i in variable
loop
 string_result := string_result || string1 || string2 ;
end loop
...
--send string_result in mail
...
return 1
```

When I execute this function I received:

**01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"**

**Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.**

**Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.**

Comment: Why not write the `clobs` in a text file and send that text file as an attachment ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_lob.htm#TTPLP66665) and [`DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_lob.htm#TTPLP66758).

Something like:

```
DECLARE
  string_result CLOB;
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( string_result, TRUE );
  FOR i IN variable LOOP
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( string_result, LENGTH( string1 ), string1 );
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( string_result, LENGTH( string2 ), string2 );
  END LOOP;
  --send string_result in mail
END;
```